# Make on image larger without messing with formatting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website I'm making updates to, and one of the updates is making an image in the center larger without causing the text and alignment to change. The pictures below are what I'm working on and what I want to avoid.

[image: What I Have]

[image: What I'm trying to avoid]

Basically, I need the logo in the middle to be larger without messing with how the text is lined up, but whenever I make it larger it pushes all the text down and takes the logo out of the center. Below is the code for the area I'm working on and the images..

**HTML**

```
<div class="padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center mt-30">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="text-icons" ><img src="images/<?php echo $icons[2]["icon_img"]; ?>"></div>
        <div class="featureitem img-item">
          <!-- <strong >Empowerment</strong> -->
          <p class="">An innovative approach that drives the discovery of new medicines. By collaborating with Circuit Clinical’s network, we have empowered individuals to take charge of the journey to finding cures through their participation.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="text-icons-middle" >
        <img src="images/<?php echo $icons[0]["icon_img"]; ?>">
      </div>
        <div class="featureitem img-item">
         <!--  <strong >Engagement</strong> -->
          <p class="">We are an Integrated Research Organization [IRO] dedicated to optimizing the clinical research experience by delivering a comprehensive research program into our physicians practices. We make clinical research more manageable with our dedicated team of research professionals who match clinical trials to a physician’s areas of interest, assist with patient recruitment and study visits while filing all regulatory requirements.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
<!--       <div class="border"></div> -->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="text-icons" ><img src="images/<?php echo $icons[1]["icon_img"]; ?>"></div>
        <div class="img-item">
          <!--   <strong >Enablement</strong> -->
          <p class="">Transforms the experience of finding and participating in clinical trials for patients everywhere. It empowers prospective patients to confidently select a trial site trusted by their peers. Sites, sponsors and CROs leverage TrialScout<sup>TM</sup> to share their story and engage patients to consider participating in their trials.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  <!--     <div class="border"></div> -->

      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-icons img{
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.text-icons-middle img{
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "position" method to avoid this problem, just set the "position" of parent div to "relative" and the div of "text" to "absolute", then set the text to have a fixed-top value. So when you increase the size of the picture, it wont effect the position of below text. I had made a simple program for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CSS Template</title>
<style>
#parent_div{
position: relative;
}
#div_image{
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color: green;
height:100px;
width: 300px;
}

#div_text{
position: absolute;
top:150px;
left:0px;
size:5px;
height:100px;
width: 300px;
}

#button{
position: absolute;
left:400px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent_div">
    <div id="div_image">
        <img src="">
    <div>

    <div id="div_text">
    Basically, I need the logo in the middle to be larger without messing with how the text is lined up, but whenever I make it larger it pushes all the text down and takes the logo out of the center. Below is the code for the area I'm working on and the images.. 
    </div>
</div>

<button id="button" type="button" onclick="inc_size()">Increase size</button>

<script>
function inc_size(){
    var test = document.getElementById("div_image").style.height = "150px";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```